# Apollo Graphql Creating Directives Replacing field.type with a custom GraphQLScalarType

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am creating a custom directive based on the next documentation:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/features/creating-directives.html#Enforcing-value-restrictions
and a have a question about the comment "Replace field.type with a custom GraphQLScalarType th ...."

```
    ...
    visitFieldDefinition(field) {
        this.wrapType(field);
    }

    // Replace field.type with a custom GraphQLScalarType that enforces the
    // length restriction.
    wrapType(field) {
        if (
    ...
```

The example creates a new GraphQLScalarType and replace the initial type, so I am losing the initianl Type (String, ID, etc)

How Can I use visitInputFieldDefinition without replaces the initial type? Is it posible to use method resolve? like in method visitFieldDefinition

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no resolve on input types, though [it has been asked for](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/858).